# Repeat alphabets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you ensure that a word taken in through a function repeats each of its alphabets in the output.

Example:

word("Hello")`should return`HHeelllloo`

word("Hi-Tech")`should return`HHii--TTeecchh`

Comment: Please, check [ask] and also [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what `def` means.

Comment: @khelwood I started python yesterday. So my understanding is it that we use it to write define a function. So please feel free to let me know what does it mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```py
def word(txt):
    new_txt = ""
    for letter in txt:
        new_txt += letter*2

    return new_txt
```

Basically, for every letter, you add 2 of the letter (`letter*2`) to a string, which you return at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` this is along the lines of The Pilot Dude's answer just in one line:

```
data = "Hello"
print(''.join(l*2 for l in data))
```

---

```
HHeelllloo
```